# Finding conditions of non existence of Periodic orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

$$
x'=y \mbox{ and } y'=ax-by-x^2y-x^3
$$
I need non-existence of periodic orbits. Which conditions $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ must satisfy?

First, one can see that if $a\leq 0$, then the system has just one equilibrium point, (0,0).

If $a>0$, then there are 3 equilibrium points (0,0), $(\pm a^{\frac{1}{2}}, 0)$.

I tried to use a Lyapunov function of the form $V(x,y)=\pm ax^2 +y^2$ (depending on $a$) to limit (or not) an orbit, but it is really boring because there was a lot of possibilities to analyze.

Is there any simpler way to look at this problem?

Comment: I forgot. Without using Bendixson criteria.

Comment: Playing with linear combinations of $x^2$, $y^2$ and $x^4$ seems promising. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

from bendxson negative test i think it is enough to show that fx +gy change sign fx=0
      gy=-b-x^2
fx+gy=0-b-x^2=-(b+x^2)  there is no sign change  it means always it is negative so we conclude that there is no periodic solutions

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use Mathjax and write a more detailed answer :)